# Microsoft Graph API @odata.count not returned when using $search parameter on messages endpoint

Tags: azure-web-app-service, microsoft-graph-api

I am calling this endpoint: `/users/{email-address}/mailFolders/Inbox/messages?$select=isRead,hasAttachments,subject,from,bodyPreview,receivedDateTime&$top=25&search="{search-term}"&$count=true`

the response only returns `@odata.context`, `@odata.nextLink`, and `value`.

When removing the `$search` parameter from the query, the response returns `@odata.count` as well.

I am using the `@odata.count` to calculate how many pages of results there are. I would prefer to not use the `skipToken` and only use `$top` and `$skip` to paginate the results.

Anyone else encounter this before/have a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move comment to answer for others' reference.

Using `$search` and `$count` together won't return the `@odata.count currently.

As `$search` requests are limited to 250 results, you can only get up to 250 items in the response.

So in this case I assume that your data is less than 250. The workaround is, use `$top=250&$search="{search-term}"` in the request to get all the results, and then get the count of the results with the method provided by the package (other than Microsoft SDK) in your code.

Comment: This will have to do for now... In order to avoid grabbing all of the data for all 250 messages, I am using batching and sending 25 requests (using 2 separate batch requests) to get the messages individually by ID and then piecing them together from the response.